# How can I push a 10GB file to git?

Tags: git, github

I have a game demo I would like to include on my github repo, however the .pak file is 9GB.  Is it possible to push such a large file? Anything I try to push over 1GB seems to not work so usually I push in increments less than that, but I can't do that with the .pak file.  Are there better alternatives to git where I can upload the demo and just have the link on my git account?

Comment: Git is meant for code source control. Not for file storage. Just upload your apk on any free file hosting service and just include the download link into your readme file or something? Google drive offers 15gb for free for example.

Comment: I tried google a while back and for some reason it didn't properly upload my file which is why I wanted to try git.  I will try compressing it and see if that works, thanks.

Comment: Try `git lfs`. It's not a good idea to check in large binaries directly. Even if the remote repository allows you to upload them, you could encounter many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Git itself does not have any significant limitations on file size, unless you're on Windows or using a 32-bit binary, where the limitation is 4 GiB.  *However*, Git is not designed for handling large binary files, and Git repositories generally should not be used for storing build artifacts.  Git is not a good tool for asset storage because it tracks history, and you typically don't care about that (or its deltification) for binary assets.

GitHub has a limitation on the size of files you can upload in a repository, and that is 100 MB.  You *can* use Git LFS for this sort of thing, but that's just moving the storage outside of your repository; you still have the problem that these files don't belong as part of a repository at all.

You'd generally want to store this file elsewhere and provide a link.  GitHub does allow release assets, but they are limited to 2 GB, so you'll need to store this file somewhere else.